# Creating a new column in Pandas based on the values of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column in Pandas dataset, based on the values for two other columns.

```
+-----------+----------+
| Column_1  | Column_2 |
+-----------+----------+
| a         | c        |
+-----------+----------+
| b         | d        |
+-----------+----------+
```

Now, `new_column` should look like:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Column_1  | Column_2 | new_column |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| a         | c        | a,c        |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| b         | d        | b,d        |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

I used this one, and it just worked fine:

```
df['new_column'] = df['Column_1']+ ' , ' +df['Column_2']
```

Comment: What if you have more than two columns such as `'Column_3': ['d','e']` . I mean you need to explicitly add `' , ' +df['Column_3']` too. E.g. would yield harcoding for each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an auxiliary dataframe(`df_new`) while applying `concat` in order to unpivot unified columns along with the `index` column generated. Then use `apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))` after grouping by new `index` column such as

```
import pandas as pd

fields = {'Column_1': ['a','b'],
          'Column_2': ['c','d']
          }

df=pd.DataFrame(fields)
df_new = pd.concat([df[i] for i in df.columns]).reset_index()
df['new_column']=df_new.groupby(['index'])[0].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()[0]
```

Comment: I think groupby is not needed